# Take parameter from listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, textbox

i have this code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sc = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd;
            sc.Open();
            cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Zapas OFF INSERT INTO Zapas (Zapas.Sezona,.....)SELECT Zapas.Sezona,... FROM Zapas WHERE ID_zapas=@ID;", sc);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text)).Value = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("box1"); 

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sc.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/Zapasy_seznam.aspx");
        }
    }
```

I need take value ID from listview, but with this code I have this error:

```
...expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied....
```

This part of my listview...

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID_zapas" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" style="text-align: center ">       
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <tr style="background-color: #e9ffe9;color: #284775;text-align:center">
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="box1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID_zapas") %>' Visible="false" />
```

...

```
<td style="width:50px;background-color:white">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Visible='<%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin") %>' CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="javascript: return confirm('Opravdu chcete zápas zkopírovat?');">
                                     <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Icons/copy.png" Width="29px" Height="29px" ToolTip="Zkopírovat zápas" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>                      
                        </tr>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Have you some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, please try this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box1 = (TextBox)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.FindControl("box1");
    using (var sc = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var cmd = sc.CreateCommand())
        {
            sc.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Zapas OFF INSERT INTO Zapas (Zapas.Sezona,.....)SELECT Zapas.Sezona,... FROM Zapas WHERE ID_zapas=@ID;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", box1.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sc.Close();
            Response.Redirect("~/Zapasy_seznam.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

When using data-aware controls such as a `ListView` here, the controls are created with automatic unique IDs per data item. This means that you can have more than 1 of the same control (such as "box1" in this case) within the page that should be referenced by the data item (`((LinkButton)sender).Parent` which is `ListViewDataItem`, representing the row).

`ListViewDataItem.FindControl` will find controls of a specific server ID within its own child scope, allowing you to get values for controls within the same row of the button that is being clicked.

Comment: Now i have this error: 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What type of control is `ListView1.FindControl("box1")` returning? Is it a TextBox control? You have cast it to `TextBox` but the error you have indicates it isn't a TextBox.

Comment: it is textbox: <asp:TextBox ID="box1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID_zapas") %>' Visible="false" />

Comment: Are you unable to reference it by name? I'll edit the post to give an example.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll edit with an explanation for future reference.